# Get data from JSON using conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON and I want to get data from JSON using conditions in javascript.

When loading the page, the Product HTML `table` is loading. In that table `tbody`, there is a `td` which has an `id`.

Here I want to do if JSON `product_id` value equals to that `td`s `id` value print `currency_symbol` to that `td`. I have mentioned my tried code below.

Products HTML table:

```
 <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Currencies</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each products}}
    <script>  
    $(document).ready(function(){
      insert_items_onload({{id}});
    });
  </script>
    <tr>
      <td>{{this.id}}</td>
      <td>
      <div>
        <table class="cur_symbol">
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Final output should be:

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Currencies</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td id='1'>
        <div>
          <table class="cur_symbol">
            <tbody>
               <tr><td>€</td></tr>
               <tr><td>£</td></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td id='2'>
        <div>
          <table class="cur_symbol">
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td id='3'>
        <div>
          <table class="cur_symbol">
            <tbody>
               <tr><td>$</td></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td id='4'>
        <div>
          <table class="cur_symbol">
            <tbody>
               <tr><td>€</td></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You have a `script` tag that is not properly closed, variables `currency_name` and `rate` that are not defined,... You probably want to pass the whole `item` object to `insert_items_symbol`, and take those properties from there. These seem quite basic errors, compared to the task you are trying to achieve. Did you debug at all??

Comment: Don't use the `json` tag (and word) in your question. There is no JSON explicitly mentioned, only a JavaScript Object literal. JSON should be reserved for the data exchange format, not for literals in JavaScript code. Read the `json` tag usage description, especially the part in capitals.

Comment: @trincot I am totally new to JS and programming. So I tried this task by searching for 2 days. I have no idea further how can I implement this. Here I want to do `If `JSON `product_id` equals to the `td` `id`. That `td` should display `currency_symbol` in a table. That was the thisng I tried there.

Comment: Seems pretty common.  Large majority of the posts I've seen are riddled with typos and/or missing code integral to the functioning of the code.  You'd think they were testing us or something.

Comment: so what templating language are you using there?

Comment: @user120242 I am using handlebars and Nodejs

Comment: hm, the template you have in your javascript code doesn't match your output.  but it's close enough.  are you getting errors?

Comment: It seems you are updating the question as we pinpoint problems. The script tag is still not properly closed. The jQuery selector on the id cannot work. An id selector needs a hash(#) prefix. And a prepend on a tbody seems wrong also: you would want to replace it, right?

Comment: @user120242. No errors. I don't know why is that. Can you please help me with an answer.

Comment: @trincot `you would want to replace it, right?`. yes I want that.

Comment: I don't think we help you with an answer, since there are several basic errors in your code. If you are *totally* new to JavaScript, why did you choose to tackle handlebars, jQuery, CSS selectors, ... at the same time. Surely there are better ways to get a first grip on JavaScript?

Comment: If you want to replace the tbody, then what made you decide on using `prepend`? I don't get it.

Comment: @trincot I have tried this in another way previously. I gave up that. I will update the question with that. Because it gave me some output.

Comment: @trincot I updated my previous try. It gave me an answer. But all currencies symbol prints the same `td`. That is why I tried another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned your code into a working example.

Mostly followed along with your code.  I'm wondering why you aren't using handlebars to do this, since you're already using it.  Your product_ids overlap, so this logic seems to be faulty.  I just added code to search for the id, find the closest tr, and replace the HTML with the string you had there.

```js
comname={};


comname.newCurrency = [{
                        "id": 1,
                        "product_id": 1,
                        "currency_id": 2,
                        "rate": "1.01",
                        "currency_name": "EUR",
                        "currency_symbol": "€"
                    }, {
                        "id": 2,
                        "product_id": 1,
                        "currency_id": 3,
                        "rate": "1.02",
                        "currency_name": "GBP",
                        "currency_symbol": "£"
                    }, {
                        "id": 3,
                        "product_id": 3,
                        "currency_id": 1,
                        "rate": "1.03",
                        "currency_name": "AUD",
                        "currency_symbol": "$"
                    }, {
                        "id": 4,
                        "product_id": 4,
                        "currency_id": 2,
                        "rate": "1.04",
                        "currency_name": "EUR",
                        "currency_symbol": "€"
                    }];


   $(document).ready(function(){
      insert_items_onload();
   });

function insert_items_onload(){
  $('.cur_symbol tr').remove();
  comname.newCurrency.forEach(
    item => insert_items_symbol(item.product_id,item.currency_symbol)
  );
}

function insert_items_symbol(id, currency_symbol){
 /*     var symbols_table = `<table>
                           <tbody>
                             <tr id="${id}">    
                               <td>${currency_symbol}</td>
                             </tr>
                           </tbody>
                          </table>`;*/
                          $(`#${id}`).prepend(`<td>${currency_symbol}</td>`);


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Currencies</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<script>
// don't use this part, just a lazy hack to generate dummy test html
[1,3,4,2,5].forEach(id=>document.write(`    <tr>
      <td>${id}</td>
      <td id="${id}">
      <div>
        <table class="cur_symbol">
          <tbody>
             <tr><td>clearme</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      </td>
    </tr>`));
</script>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: id attribute must be unique.  those values overlap.  you will either need to use a different attribute name, or rethink your data structure.  Also, are the appended tables being different in structure intentional?

Comment: I corrected it changing `$(`#${id}`).closest('tr').html(symbols_table);` to `$(`#${id}`).closest('td').html(symbols_table);`

Comment: you want to add another td under ,currency_symbol I'm guessing?  and you want to prevent duplicates?

Comment: the current problem is it shows only one currency. But some should show several currencies. Why is that?

Comment: because you are overwriting it.

Comment: try taking the example I've made here and create your own working example in the original question

Comment: you mean like this?

Comment: oh, sorry it didn't save.  I meant this?  if you want to clear the values, you can have it set html to empty in the onload function

Comment: you mean using this `$(".cur_symbol tr").remove();` can i do it?